# Why client in google chrome can not connect to websocket with ssl

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet, reactphp

client can't connect to secure websocket with google chrome

```
error: WebSocket connection to wss://web:port failed
```

but can connect to secure websocket with firefox.

I'm using reactphp and ratchet libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by ignoring peer verification `'verify_peer' => false`

```
$options = ['local_cert' => '...', 'local_pk' => '...', 'verify_peer' => false];
$socket = new SecureServer($socket, $loop, $options);
```